# Is there a mis-print on the Grabby Guts card?

Tags: munchkin

In Munchkin Zombies, the Grabby Guts card says "You have one extra Hand", but in the bottom right corner, it says "-1 Hand".  Shouldn't it say "+1 Hand" in the corner?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a little counter-intuitive, but "-1 Hand" is actually correct.  You aren't allowed to use more than 2 hands-worth of items; to check this, you can add up the number of "hands" on all your used items.

If you have two 1-hand items, "1 hand" + "1 hand" = "2 hands".

If you have two 1-hand items, plus Grabby Guts, you'll have "1 hand" + "1 hand" + "-1 hand" = "1 hand", leaving you with one hand left.

Comment: A succinct way of describing the "1 hand," "-1 hand," etc. verbiage is that the term describes the **number of hands used** to wield the item.

Comment: A never think about doing the maths with hands

Comment: BTW, the Two-Handed Sword from _Munchkin 3: Clerical Errors_ works exactly the same way: it takes up a total of -1 hand, on account of having two hands of its own.